# jenkins job triggering downstram job with paramenters not working

Tags: jenkins, plugins, docker

I am trying to execute a downstream job using the [jenkins plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) to pass the parameters to the downstream job. I have added the following configuration as a build step: [image: the following configuration as a build step:]. The top job completes successfully however in the downstream job, where I am using jenkins plugin for docker build and push, it does not accept the JBNAME :

```
Building in workspace /home/jenkins/workspace/dockerbuild
ERROR: Unrecognized macro '**JBNAME**' in 'url/repo/**${JBNAME**}'
org.jenkinsci.plugins.tokenmacro.MacroEvaluationException:               Unrecognized    macro 'JBNAME' in 'url/repo/**${JBNAME}**'
at  org.jenkinsci.plugins.tokenmacro.TokenMacro.expand(TokenMacro.java:207)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.tokenmacro.TokenMacro.expandAll(TokenMacro.java:246)
at org.jenkinsci.plugins.tokenmacro.TokenMacro.expandAll(TokenMacro.java:232)
at com.cloudbees.dockerpublish.DockerBuilder$Perform.expandAll(DockerBuilder.java:324)
at com.cloudbees.dockerpublish.DockerBuilder$Perform.getImageTags(DockerBuilder.java:336)
at com.cloudbees.dockerpublish.DockerBuilder$Perform.exec(DockerBuilder.java:305)
at com.cloudbees.dockerpublish.DockerBuilder$Perform.access$100(DockerBuilder.java:291)
at com.cloudbees.dockerpublish.DockerBuilder.perform(DockerBuilder.java:262)
at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:779)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:205)
at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:162)
at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:534)
at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1720)
at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:404)
Build step 'Docker Build and Publish' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

When I look at the parameters link on the failed build page, the field is empty, it did not pass any parameters, including current or predefined:
[image]
I am lost at the moment. I really need to pass the upstream job name to the docker build job in order to preserve the proper container naming.

Thank You very much!

Answer (score 1):

Recent Jenkins versions do not allow undeclared parameters anymore. See related [security advisory](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/SECURITY/Jenkins+Security+Advisory+2016-05-11) for details.

In your case the you probably could just declare the `JBNAME` as a parameter for the downstream job. I.e. select
*This build is parameterized* in the downstream job configuration and add new string parameter of name `JBNAME`.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply. Looks like it worked! If i specify it like this, will I be able to change the value with the one defined in the upstream job? The reason being is I need to use the dockerbuild job by multiple upstream jobs with different values

Comment: Yes, you can call the build with any value from any upstream job as long as the parameter name is the same (in your case `JBNAME`) both in the upstream and the downstream.